# Calling external DLL from network drive on Windows 7

Tags: c#, networking

I have to call some external dll-s from network drive on Windows 7 machine. So first thing i had to do was to give the network share full trust with caspol.exe. Now i can call the external dll -s but only when i run the application as administrator on windows 7. 
What else should i do to not have to run the application as administrator? Is this even possible without admin rights under windows 7?

EDIT:
Coping the files to local machine is not a option.

This is how im loading the dll:

```
dll = Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath);
type = dll.GetType(dllNamespace);
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("Execute");
return (string)method.Invoke(type, new Object[2] { data1, data2 });
```

The error im getting when i dont run the application as admin is here:

```
Exception: SecurityException? - "Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken?=b77a5c561934e089' failed."
```

Comment: Since you could always copy the dll files locally you should be able to run them. What kind of DLL files are they. What errors are you having and what's going wrong. How is you're machine secured and can you start generic executables from network shares? Give some more information so we ca help you.

Comment: You should not be trying to register/link files on a network drive.  Copy the file to the local computer.  In your solution you can use the reference on the remote location if you want, provided you set the properties of the reference, to create a local copy.

Comment: @Ramhound +1 I agree completely. This is an extremely risky thing to do. It is setting up the user for all kinds of obscure error conditions. Very poor practice indeed.